# Mac-specific steps in a GitHub Actions build matrix

Tags: github-actions

I am new to GitHub Actions, and I am trying to set up a build matrix that installs different system requirements on different platforms. From the example at https://github.com/r-lib/actions/blob/master/examples/check-standard.yaml, I figured out how to write steps that only run on Windows:

```
      - name: step name
        if: runner.os == 'Windows'
```

or Linux

```
      - name: Install system dependencies
        if: runner.os == 'Linux'
```

But if I try `if: runner.os == 'Mac'`, my step gets skipped on Mac OS. So my questions are

1. What `runner.os` name do I use for Mac OS, and
2. Where can I refer to the list of possible `runner.os` names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`macOS` is what you looking for:

```
- name: doing something on macOS
  if: runner.os == 'macOS'
```

You can refer the different `os` type in [`runner` context doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#runner-context).